# Bit shifting limit?

Tags: c#, bit, bit-shift, bitmask, cidr

I'm trying to create a subnet mask from CIDR notation eq. `/8` would mean that the 8 leading bits would be 1's. I'm achieving this by left shifting (I'm working with 32 bits here) `(uint)(0xffffffff << (32-8))`.

The code works fine until I get a `/0` mask which leads to the code `(uint)(0xffffffff << 32)`

Now left shifting `(uint)(0xffffffff << 31)` works as intended `10000000.00000000.00000000.00000000`.

But left shifting `(uint)(0xffffffff << 32)` gives `11111111.11111111.11111111.11111111`. While expected outcome would be `00000000.00000000.00000000.00000000`.

What's the simplest way around this? Handle `/0` with a if-statement and just set all to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators):

> The left-shift operation discards the high-order bits that are outside the range of the result type and sets the low-order empty bit positions to zero

That means for shifting left on a 32-bit type, only the low 5 bits in the shift count is taken. Since 32 = 0b10_0000 which needs 6 bits to store and after masking out the low 5 bits it'll become zero. So `0xffffffff << 32` is equivalent to `0xffffffff << 0`

To solve that you either need to shift in a higher precision

```
return (uint)(((1UL << mask) - 1) << (32 - mask))
```

or check the shift count before shifting

```
return mask == 0 ? 0xFFFFFFFFU : 0xFFFFFFFFU << (32 - mask);
```

The latter is better on 32-bit platforms

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the correct algorithm would be something like:

`0xffffffff & (uint)((((ulong)0x1 << mask) - 1) << (32-mask))`

Where `mask` is the number after the /

I've implemented it in c# here (since you don't specify a language), and seems to work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/j1IfZP

Comment: the `0xffffffff &` part is redundant because casting to uint already truncates to the low 32 bits